# what(): bad_weak_ptr

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a constructor which looks like this:

```
OdomNode::OdomNode() : Node("odometry_node","odometry_node_ns", rclcpp::NodeOptions()), _rate(30), _ticks_meter(1), _left_pos{0},
                       _right_pos{0}, _enc_left{0}, _enc_right{0}, _lmult{0},
                       _rmult{0}, _prev_rencoder{0}, _prev_lencoder{0},
                       _d_left{0}, _d_right{0}, q{std::make_shared<tf2::Quaternion>()},
                       _base_frame_id{"base_footprint"}, _odom_frame_id{"odom"},
                       _odom_ts{std::make_shared<geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped>()}, _loop_rate{30},
                       _then{}, _odom_pub{}, _odom_tb{std::make_shared<tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster>(shared_from_this())}
{
    _then = this->now();
    rclcpp::QoS qos(rclcpp::KeepLast(7));
    _odom_pub = this->create_publisher<nav_msgs::msg::Odometry>("odom", qos);
    //_odom_tb = odom_tf2_broadcaster(this->);
    _rate = this->declare_parameter("rate", 30);
    _ticks_meter = this->declare_parameter("ticks_meter", 1400000);
    _base_frame_id = this->declare_parameter("base_frame", "base_footprint");

}
```

And I also have the loop function of that class:

```
 void OdomNode::update()
{
    while(rclcpp::ok())
    {
        this->loop();
        this->_loop_rate.sleep();
        rclcpp::spin(shared_from_this());
    }
```

Whenever I run I get an error that I have a bad_weak_ptr. I have tried to declare and initialzie the shared_ptr in my update function:

```
   void OdomNode::update()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> _for_spin = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>(this);
        while(rclcpp::ok())
        {
            this->loop();
            this->_loop_rate.sleep();
            rclcpp::spin(_for_spin);
        }
```

But I get an error:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘rclcpp::Node::Node(odom_node::OdomNode*)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }

}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330261/what():--bad_weak_ptr/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-08-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is this line

```
_odom_tb{std::make_shared<tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster>(shared_from_this())}
```

You are trying to get a shared pointer from `this` in the initialization phase, even though the constructor isn't fully completed yet and therefore `this` doesn't point to a correct instance.

As a workaround, you can try to call the constructor for the `StaticTransformBroadcaster` [0] with a raw `this` pointer or introduce a separate `init` function for your odomNode.

[0] https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/ros2/tf2_ros/include/tf2_ros/static_transform_broadcaster.h#L53-L63

---

Originally posted by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) with karma: 643 on 2019-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-08-08**:
@Karsten great, I can see that it accepts r value for the object, which exactly what is needed but how then it is created? Does it  create a new shared_ptr inside that statictransform constructor?

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-08-08**:
@Karsten turns out to be that the problem is behind the while loop and make_shared that passed insie the spin function!